# Titanium Android module: notification click shows nothing

Tags: android, notifications, titanium, android-pendingintent, titanium-modules

I'm writing an Android module for a titanium app. I a adding notification for when we enter the area of a beacon (probably not relevant). I am firing my notification from the module class (subclass of KrollModule).

The problem is: when I click the notification it does nothing! It only cancels the notification.

Here's my code:

```
private void postNotification(String msg) {
    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context, TiApplication.getInstance().getCurrentActivity().getClass());
    notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context,
            0,
            notifyIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_overlay)
    .setContentTitle("Notify Demo")
    .setContentText(msg)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .build();
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

    try {
        beaconManager.stopMonitoring(region);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    beaconManager.disconnect();

}
```

And here is the log:

```
W/ActivityManager(755): Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x20000000 cmp=com.....banking/org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity bnds=[0,153][1080,345] } from null (pid=-1, uid=10360) not exported from uid 10367
V/PanelView(868): animationTick called with dtms=0; nothing to do (h=1776.0 v=-6000.0)
W/ActivityManager(755): Unable to send startActivity intent
W/ActivityManager(755): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x20000000 cmp=com.....banking/org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity bnds=[0,153][1080,345] } from null (pid=-1, uid=10360) not exported from uid 10367
W/ActivityManager(755):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1186)
W/ActivityManager(755):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:741)
W/ActivityManager(755):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:3300)
W/ActivityManager(755):     at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:252)
W/ActivityManager(755):     at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.send(PendingIntentRecord.java:192)
W/ActivityManager(755):     at android.content.IIntentSender$Stub.onTransact(IIntentSender.java:64)
W/ActivityManager(755):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
W/ActivityManager(755):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

For what I can see the problem is in how I create the `PendingIntent`... I want that when the user clicks the notification it opens the app. No matter how or where... it can be on the activity where the user left, the login page, the splash page, or whatever.

Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After some (a lot) of search and work I've found a solution that works (and can be useful for someone else).

The problem was `TiApplication.getInstance().getCurrentActivity().getClass()`... it seems like at this time of the application run there is still no `Activity`.

Using `TiApplication.getAppRootOrCurrentActivity().getClass()` fixed the problem getting the root activity of the app.